# qnorm() in R programming

Tags: r

Just started learning R, and I am curious to know how to handle this problem in R.

What score from a standard normal distribution cuts off the first 25% of the data? (That is the 25% quantile of a standard normal distribution)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Do you have a reproducible example of what you've tried? (I know you're stuck, but showing us how your stuck would improve your question). As written, your question reads like you want us to code it for you and SO is not a coding service. Also, What package is `gnorm` in? It's not part of base R.

Comment: maybe edit the title to `qnorm`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tigerstats/vignettes/qnorm.html) on the `qnorm` function. Example:

```
# generate normal data
n <- 100
data <- rnorm(n,0,1)

# compute the score that cuts of the first 25% of the data
score <- qnorm(0.25, mean(data), sd(data))

# test it to be sure
length(data[data>=score])
[1] 75
length(data[data<score])
[1] 25
```

Comment: Why this test looks different?
<br>
> score <- qnorm(.50, mean=0, sd=1)
> length(data[data>=score])
[1] 47
> length(data[data<score])
[1] 53

Comment: @JoeGosh `data` is a randomly generated vector. It was generated from a normal distribution, so you would expect approximately 50 values to be over the mean and 50 to be under, but not exactly. A 47/53 split is not surprising.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.